# If $\{\nabla u_j\}$ is Cauchy in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\int_{B(0,1)} u_j dx = 0$, does $\{u_j\}$ converge in $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $1 < p < \infty$. Let $\{u_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of functions in $W^{1,p}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that

1. $\nabla u_j \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $j$,
2. $\int_{B(0,1)} u_j dx = 0$ for all $j$,
3. $\{ \nabla u_j \}_{j= 1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

> I would like to know whether $\{u_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (and hence convergent in $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ since this space is a Frechet space).  That is, I would like to know whether it can be shown that, for any ball $B(0,r)$:
>
> $$\|u_j - u_k \|_{L^p(B(0,r))}^p \to 0 $$
>
> as $j$ and $k$ become large.

This result is claimed to be true in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3970) paper on arXiv (see Proposition 2.1). The details of the proof are not supplied.

If 2. above is replaced by the condition that $\int_{B(0,r)} u_j dx = 0$ for all $r$ and all $j$, then I can get the result by applying Poincare's inequality for a ball (see Theorem 2 in section 5.8 from Evan's PDE book), and then and using 3. However, with only the weaker condition I'm not sure how to proceed.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps try rescaling the ball ?

Comment: @CheeHan - I tried to make a rescaling argument work, but wasn't able to get anywhere, because having zero integral over $B(0,1)$ does not imply having a zero integral over a ball of any other size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vanishing integral over the small ball is enough to get a Poincaré-type estimate. Let $B = B(0,1)$ and $\Omega = B(0,r)$.

We define $$\|u\|_\star := \big|\int_B u \, \mathrm dx\big| + \|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$

It is clear that $\|\cdot\|_\star$ is a norm on $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and that $\|u\|_\star \le C \, \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}$ for some $C > 0$. Moreover, one can show that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is complete w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_\star$. From the bounded inverse theorem, we get a constant $M>0$ such that $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} \le M \, \|u\|_\star$. Note that $M$ may (and, surely, will) depend on $r$, but this does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you please provide a few more details explaining why $\| \cdot \|_\star$ is a norm and why we have the completeness? I tried to show those myself and I got stuck on the first step of showing that $\| u \|_\star = 0$ implies that the $L^p(\Omega)$ norm of $u$ is zero.

Comment: If $\|u\|_\star = 0$, $u$ has to be constant due to the second term. Hence, it is zero. For the completeness: If $\{u_n\}$ is Cauchy, we denote by $c_n$ the mean value of $u_n$, thus $\{u_n - c_n\}$ has to converge in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ towards some $u$. Then, since $\int_B u_n\,\mathrm dx$ converges, you have $\|u_n - u - c\|_\star \to 0$ for some suitable $c$.

Comment: @gerw Why is that $\{u_n - c_n\}$ converges in $W^{1,p}$?

Comment: For functions with zero mean you can estimate the $W^{1,p}$ norm by the $W^{1,p}$ seminorm. Hence, this sequence is a Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,p}$.